# Ruby assignment and comparison in one line?

Tags: ruby

It seems this doesn't work as expected:

```
if c = Countries.first.nil?
  ... do something
end
```

The comparison works but the assignment doesn't. Is there a way to do both the comparison and assignment in one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what you really want:

```
if (c = Countries.first).nil?
  # ... do something
end
```

In your example, you will get `c = (Countries.first.nil?)`, so `c` will be `false` or `true`.

You might actually write it like this:

```
unless (c = Countries.first)
  # ... do something
end
```

but caution! I would keep the `()` in place, because otherwise it will appear like you meant comparison, and the ruby interpreter will warn you.

I use this pattern sometimes, but use it sparingly, because it makes things less clear.

Comment: Why not as Reed had it? I assumed he wanted to assign c = true or false (from `.nil?`)... but I probably misread the intent of his question.

Comment: @Andrew The way Reed has it will set `c` to `Countries.first.nil?`, but he wanted to actually set `c` to `Countries.first` and then check `if c.nil?`

Comment: This is a good example of why using parenthesis is important.

Comment: Or a better example of how splitting a statement into two doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign c to Countries.first if c is nil:

```
c = Countries.first if c.nil?
```

Comment: actually, if this is what you want you can just use `c ||= Countries.first`.